# Adverse Events API data is not updated

Tags: data-request, api, openfda

We are using below API to fetch the data but it seems API data is not updated since 29th of November 23 as it shows last updated as 2023-11-29 in the response and therefore we are not able to get the latest data for the month of November:

[https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20231101+TO+20231130]AND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22BSZ%22&limit=1000](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:%5B20231101+TO+20231130%5DAND+device.device_report_product_code.exact:%22BSZ%22&limit=1000)

But when go to below URL and search for BSZ product code and put the dates as 11/01/2023 and 11/30/2023, the updated data is present on
https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfmaude/search.cfm

Kindly help as we are using the API to fetch the data.

Thanks,
Shailendra J

Answer (score 1):

We updated the Device Adverse Event dataset yesterday; could you please try again?

Comment: Hi Denis, I can see its updated, could you please let me know when the data gets fully updated as we have observed that data has been updated and available on https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/ by 10th on every month but on the API mentioned below ,it does not get updated before 14th of every month.

https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?